# How to drag a cell reference formula down a column, but move the cell reference across a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I am trying to drag a cell reference formula down a column, but have the row value increase as the formula is dragged down.

For instance, in the shot below, cell B3 has the formula "=I3". I would like to be able to drag the formula down column B so that B4's value would be "=J3", the value in B5 would be "=K9" etc..

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX($3:$3,,ROW($ZZ1)+8)
```

Now as it is dragged down it will increase the column index reference

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN($I$3)+63+ROW(A1))&ROW($I$3))
```

[image]